# What is the under the hood database in cloudera 5.x

Tags: cloudera, bigdata

Is there any under the hood database in cloudera 5.x distribution like we have DB2 in IBM distribution i.e. under BigInsights.

The need is we have small tables as part of our project along with huge tables and in hive it is taking more time to fetch data from small tables compare to any RDBMS. If we have any RDBMS under the hood in cloudera 5.x then we can create those small tables in that database.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding your question properly.

Cloudera Manager and the Cloudera CDH components do rely on a database for metadata and other bits of application data. By default, when you install Cloudera Manager and then CDH it will use an embedded postgres database. You can change this for any and all applications to use either postgresql, oracle or mysql.

For example hive stores all the metadata for the "tables" and "databases" you create in the default database or the database selected as the "Hive Metastore Database Type" in cloudera manager.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. In IBM BigInsights, there is a DB2 database under the hood and user can create very small tables (like configuration tables or very small dimension tables etc.) in DB2 database instead of HIVE. I am just checking whether there is any equivalent database for Cloudera distribution.